# Simple postgres select query hangs forever when string passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am unable to figure out why the following query fails in node.js with [pg PostgreSQL client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) (version 8.5.1).

```js
  db.query("SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE $1", ["foo"], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    console.log(results.rows)
  });
```

I do not get a error message and `db.query` function hangs forever.

However the following works, which I thought would be the same but I am obviously missing something:

```js
  db.query("SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE 'foo'", ...
```

My table looks like this and have less then 10 rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR ( 128 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

In case it is relevant, `db.query` is called from a express app endpoint handler. Also, passing parameters/values to INSERT statements works.

Edit: A prepared statement also works, still do not understand why above do not.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 10 means that the table is practically empty :-D  do you have any other process running that involves `my_table`?  This query looks fine `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE 'foo%'` ..

Comment: @JimJones no there should be no other process using the db.

Comment: When in doubt check the Postgres log. In `postgresql.conf'` temporarily crank `log_statement` up 'all' and reload server. Then run your parameterized query and see what is actually hitting the server.  Remember to reset `log_statement` afterwards to avoid clogging the logs.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this type of problem? I am seeing a similar behavior on my end